# Retrieve all Records for a particular Month using start_end and end_date

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have the a table with the follow structure and data

```
Product           startdate         enddate 
ProdA             01/01/2020        15/01/2020
ProdB             29/01/2020        02/02/2020
ProdC             02/02/2020        03/03/2020
ProdD             20/12/2019        20/12/2020
```

I need an sql query for redshift that returns me all the product which were valid for a month I provide. The validity for a month is considered if that product had any day for that month in between startdate and enddate

so if I am passing the date 01/01/2020 (This can be modified based on solution if you want to format it to YYYY-mm for example.) I am looking for records which were valid in January 2020 and would expect the following products returned

ProdA
ProdB
ProdD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this logic:

```
where startdate <= last_day('2020-01-01') and
      enddate >= '2020-01-01'
```

That is, there is an overlap if the start date is before the end of the month and the end date is on or after the start of the month.